# Cross-origin directives in httpd.conf?

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, htaccess

I am a part time Apache administrator (not by choice). We have an animated gif hit counter. I want to add a CSP to disable active content, but include a CORS policy to allow the gif for the hit counter.

I found an example of adding the [CORS policy to ***`.htaccess`***](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess), but its not the ***`httpd.conf`*** file. How do I take the following ***`.htaccess`***:

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

And add it to ***`.httpd.conf`***?

Answer (score 2):

The file format is *exactly the same*, except as `httpd.conf` is global, you should put these settings within the apropriate `<VirtualHost…>` block (and possibly even within a `<Path>` or `<Directory>` block to improve performance, as FilesMatch is comparatively slow). For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName …
    OtherSettings …

    <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
        SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```